# JavaScript Error line 1 <ANYJAVASCRIPFILE.JS> SyntaxError: Parse error IN Iphone mobile safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, safari

I keep getting this error when I run my web app (asp.net mvc) in the mobile safari (ITouch)

JavaScript Error line 1 
 
SyntaxError: Parse error

JavaScript Error line 1 
 
SyntaxError: Parse error

I have no problem running this in any other browser (including safari).
I suspect this is something to do with mobile safari handling javascript files.
I am using MicrosoftMvcAjax.js and Jquery.

The above error is totally useless to me and I couldn't figure out where to debug or start.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Some code for us to see would be appreciated :-)

Comment: In my .master file i have this 
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 And I get this error when I load any page referencing this master page,, And the error message is JavaScript Error line 1 MicrosoftAjax.js SyntaxError: Parse Error JavaScript Error line 1 MicrosoftMvcAjax.js SyntaxError: Parse Error This happens for any Javascript file that I reference. What is the Error (line 1??) that it is complaining about? -Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is resolved by the client, which doesn't know about the application.

To get a relative path for the client, you can write

```
<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the src attribute for the Javascript is the problem.
For some reason  is taking me to the domain root instead of the application root.
So instead of looking for http://localhost/application/scripts , the page is looking under
http://scripts...Don't know why? 
The Parser error is simply file not found error.
Thanks everyone